# identify the name or the id with farbtastic

Tags: jquery, html, color-picker, farbtastic

I have about 8 type:

```
<input type="text" id="color1" name="color1" class="colorwell" value="#ffffff" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" id="color8" name="color8" class="colorwell" value="#ffffff" />
```

I have the color in a varaibile

```
 $('#picker').farbtastic('#color_picker_input').mouseup(function (){
      var colore = $.farbtastic('#picker').color;
 alert(colore);});
```

but I would also like to identify the name or id

something that looks like

```
var nome = $.farbtastic('#picker').name;
```

This does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you want to end up with, an array of all the element `id`s, an object of their properties, or a single variable that's over-written every time a new `id` is found?

Answer (score 7):

I've not used Farbtastic, but you should be able to `console.log($.farbtastic('#picker'))` to view all the information about that object in the JavaScript console. From this you can determine what the name is stored as or how to get the name (if it's a method instead).

You may also be able to just use jQuery's default `attr()` method:

```
$.farbtastic('#picker').attr('name');
// Or
$('#picker').attr('name');
```

I've just tried this on the official site and this is in fact the case:

[image]

Based on the [Farbtastic documentation](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/), there is no way to call `name` or `id` through the `farbtastic` object. You'll need to fall back to generic jQuery:

```
$('#picker').attr('name');
$('#picker').attr('id');
```

Comment: Please explain the downvotes? This may not give a direct answer, but it does give a way to easily find out the answer... `$.farbtastic('#picker')` will be an object, and calling `console.log($.farbtastic('#picker'));` will log all properties and methods associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

To *get* all the `id`s, and push to an array:

```
var ids = [];

$('.colorwell').each(function(){
    ids.push(this.id);
});
console.log(ids);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hPB7q/).

To get other details, and populate an object, or rather an *array* of objects, with various properties:

```
var colorwells = [],
    self;

$('.colorwell').each(function(){
    self = this;
    colorwells.push(
        {
            id : self.id,
            name : self.name,
            value : self.value
        }
    );
});
console.log(colorwells);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hPB7q/1/).

Specifically to address your question, and bear in mind that I've never used farbtastic (as a developer, though I'm aware it's used widely for UI), and assuming that your posted code (to alert the colour) works, then I'd suggest:

```
$('#picker').farbtastic('#color_picker_input').mouseup(function (){
    var colore = $.farbtastic('#picker').color,
        nome = this.id || '';
        console.log(colore, nome);
});
```

This should retrieve *either* the `id` of the current DOM node, or an empty string (to prevent error messages regarding `undefined` strings/properties/objects).

While `$(this).attr('id')` or `$(this).prop('id')` *works*, it's needlessly expensive to invoke jQuery to retrieve a property of a DOM node (that's perfectly available without wrapping a node into a jQuery object).

Answer (score 0):

writing as you suggest

```
  $('#picker').farbtastic('#color_picker_input').mouseup(function (){
            var colore = $.farbtastic('#picker').color,
            nome = this.id || '';
          console.log(colore, nome);
                 // alert(nome);        
    });
```

on the console log I read:

## 21cc00 picker

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**

```
$('#picker').farbtastic('#color_picker_input').mouseup(function (){

     var   nome = $("input:text:focus").attr("id");
     var   colore = $.farbtastic('#picker').color;

          console.log( colore, nome);
...
```

in this way I determine which textbox has been used